# User timeline from twitter gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I have been trying to get a timeline of a user, which actually doesn't require a oauth token just the application level token.

I registered a sample app and got the consumer id, consumer secret, app token and app secret.. I have been trying using the twitter gem, but to no avail..

The code I am trying is,

```
 client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = 'CONSUMER_KEY'
      config.consumer_secret = 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
      config.access_token = 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
      config.access_token_secret = 'ACCESS_SECRET'
    end

    response = client.user_timeline(username)
    if response
      return response
```

And I am getting just this blank page.

```
{

    "response": [ ]

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I used list_timeline and it works perfectly even the `client.user` works good.. please help..

EDIT: I have regenerated the all the tokens, now it is return `Bad Authentication Data`

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered around it and found the issue to be, the twitter gem doesn't seem to be working only for my ID for which the oAuth token is generated, which is called using `home_timeline` not sure why they didnt' added support to it..